# RatingBar color not changed in Jellybean OS

Tags: android

I set rating bar like this and works fine kitkat or next os.But it doesn't works properly in jelly bean OS.

I tried by set custom theme but doesn't works in jellybean os.After R&D I followed many suggestions and it works fine but not in lower versions.

**Please check carefully before mark as duplicate.**

```
<RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:progressTint="@color/btn_yellow"
                    android:rating="0.0"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/black_font_color"
                    android:progressBackgroundTint="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:stepSize="0.1"
                    android:isIndicator="true"
                    />
```

I added custom XML file also with Images but didn't work properly for lower version otherwise it works fine.Please give proper answer instead of mark duplicate.

Thanks.

Comment: show your style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"

Comment: Its default style option bro...

Comment: i didn't see that :D

Answer (score 0):

Add this style :

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">  
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/indigo</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item>
```

and apply this using

```
android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
```

Comment: I found in R&D. I am talking about OS.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:progressTint="#0fff00"
    android:rating="3.0"
    android:secondaryProgressTint="#54f4ff"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:stepSize="0.1"
    android:isIndicator="false"/>
```

Comment: I did like this after R&D. It should work on jeelybean OS